# how to use jquery classed with typings within an angular7 app

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying manipulate the dom using jquery within an Angular 7 app as below

My jquery installation through npm and jquery typings both are successful. But haven't found a way yet to distinguish the Event class so as to refer to jquery Event.

Please see the sample code below

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var $:JQueryStatic;
import { AoEditorStore } from '../common/AoEditorStore';
import { ShimFactory } from './shim/ShimFactory';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-dom-editor',
  templateUrl: './dom-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dom-editor.component.scss']
})
export class DomEditorComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private toolSelector : AoEditorStore , private shimFactory : ShimFactory) { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let domEditor = this ;
    $('.editor-div').on('click' , domEditor.onElementClick).on('mouseover' , domEditor.onElementHover) ; 
  } 

  onElementClick( evt : Event) :void {
    if(this.toolSelector.isToolSelected()){

        let shim = this.shimFactory.getShimNew(this.toolSelector.getSelectedTool(), evt.pageX , evt.pageY, evt.currentTarget); 
    }

    console.log('dom editing div clicked') ;
  }

  onElementHover(obj : Event):void{
    console.log('hover on dom editing div') ;
  }

}
```

The challenge is that although jquery $ is recognized, when I refer to the  parameter of the handler as Event it defaults to lib.dom.d.ts Event class instead of jquery Event.

so when I try to access evt.pageX it gives me a compilation error.

how do I make sure the event object passed to my jquery handler defaults to jquery Event class instead of anything else.

Comment: I am using jquery since I find Renderer2 a bit limiting in its capabilities to edit the dom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `@HostListener` instead of handle event by jquery.

Add condition `event.target.matches('.editor-div')` to check element source.

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
    onclick(event) {
        if(event.target.matches('.editor-div')) {
            alert('click to editor div')
        }
    }

    @HostListener('document:mouseover', ['$event'])
    mouseover(event) {
        if(event.target.matches('.editor-div')) {
            alert('hover to editor div')
        }
    }
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hover-click-hostlistener

Comment: after looking around quite a bit, I settled for HostListener approach. An important note here is - the event objects received by the HostListener is a standard dom event so you can directly use the dom lib classes such as MouseEvent to access them. quite handy